# Save a plot in an object

Tags: r, plot

In `ggplot2`, one can easily save a graphic into a R object.

```
p = ggplot(...) + geom_point()      # does not display the graph
p                                   # displays the graph
```

The standard function `plot` produces the graphic as a void function and returns NULL.

```
p = plot(1:10)     # displays the graph
p                  # NULL
```

Is it possible to save a graphic created by `plot` in an object?

Comment: `plot` is a generic, and different `plot` methods do return such objects as far as I know. `plot.default`, however, indeed returns `NULL`.

Comment: Is your goal to be able to replot your graph only by typing `p` after saving it as an object? Or would you like to save it as an object which you would then be able to alter its values for example?

Comment: I might want to overlay other graphics on top of the saved graphic but I don't aim to modify the plot that has been created and saved. Did I answer your question? Thks

Comment: @Remi.b It does thanks. I posted a solution that might help.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

base graphics draw directly on a device.

You could use

1- `recordPlot`

2- the recently introduced [`gridGraphics` package](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/gridGraphics/gridGraphics.pdf), to convert base graphics to their grid equivalent

Here's a minimal example,

```
plot(1:10) 

p <- recordPlot()
plot.new() ## clean up device
p # redraw

## grab the scene as a grid object
library(gridGraphics)
library(grid)
grid.echo()
a <- grid.grab()

## draw it, changes optional
grid.newpage()
a <- editGrob(a, vp=viewport(width=unit(2,"in")), gp=gpar(fontsize=10))
grid.draw(a)
```

Comment: It's unclear to me: are (1) and (2) separate methods to achieve the same goal, or two steps both necessary to answer the OP's question?

Comment: @NLi10Me 2 different methods.

Comment: If I try `saveRDS(object = p, file = "p.Rds")`, then load a new R session, run `p <- readRDS(file = "p.Rds")` followed by `p`, I get an error saying `Error in replayPlot(x) : loading snapshot from a different session`. Am I saving the `p` object incorrectly?

Comment: It seems that the error I was getting was resolved in [R 3.3.0](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/DisplayList/dl-record.html), using that version it works. When I used the `gridGraphics` method shown here, the colors on the redrawn plot kept getting messed up, even with `grid.grab(wrap=TRUE)`

Comment: Why does the plot not re-draw when called from the console after it has been returned as the output of a function?

Answer (score 54):

I solved this by using a function instead of an object. For example, suppose we want to compare two beta distributions with different parameters. We can run:

```
z1<-rbeta(10000,5,5)
z2<-rbeta(10000,20,20)

plotit<-function(vector,alpha,beta){
    plot(density(vector),xlim=c(0,1))
    abline(v=alpha/(alpha+beta),lty="longdash")
}
```

And save the plots as *functions* rather than objects.

```
z.plot1<-function(){plotit(z1,5,5)}
z.plot2<-function(){plotit(z2,20,20)}
```

Next, we can call each plot as we want by simply calling the two plots as functions rather than objects.

```
z.plot1()
```

plots the first plot and

```
z.plot2()
```

plots the second.

Comment: This is very useful ! I think it is a great idea in order to prepare presets plots this is what I was searching for

Comment: This is a genius base R approach! `recordPlot` is definitely useful (if you have a window already open), but this answer is exactly what folks are looking for when they visit this post. +1!

Comment: Especially useful for complex multiple plots.

Comment: Let me join the chorus of people who really appreciate this trick. Also on behalf of my students :-)

Comment: Lexical scoping to the rescue again!  :)

Answer (score 20):

You can use the active binding feature of the `pryr` package if you don't want to directly change the values of the object created.

```
library(pryr)
a %<a-% plot(1:10,1:10)
```

Each time you type `a` on the console the graph will be reprinted on the screen. The `%<a-%` operator will rerun the script every time (in case of one graph this is not a problem I think). So essentially every time you use `a` the code will be rerun resulting in your graph which of course you can manipulate (overlay another plot on top) or save using `png` for example. No value itself will be stored in `a` however. The value will still be NULL.

I don't know if the above is what you are looking for but it might be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Thank you. That is a very handy solution. Do you know if this works if the plot is build through several lines (such as `plot(1:10);abline(v=4)` for example)? +1

Comment: @Remi.b Yeah of course it does. You need to type it like this though" `a %<a-% {plot(1:10);abline(v=4)}`. If you type it inside those curly brackets you can have as many lines as you want! Also, if you want to reassign a value to `a` you need to remove it first with `rm(a)` and then reassign it with the `%<a-%` operator otherwise you get a warning. I don't know why this happens but I guess it is not a big deal.

Comment: This is really cool! I'll have to read a bit about this package because it sounds impossible to me to do what this weird function `%<a-%` is doing. Thanks

Comment: Yeah it is another one of those really cool packages Hadley made. It is a set of functions that lets you understand the R language in depth. Have a look at `%<d-%` as well, it might come in handy later on. Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: @LyzandeR is it possible to combine the saved plots into a multiplot?

Comment: @user2300940 yes, it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723141/saving-a-base-r-plot-as-an-object-that-can-be-plotted-in-a-multiplot/42723635#42723635

Comment: If you have a function that does some computation and produces a plot as a side effect and you don't want to postpone the computation until you evaluate `a` later, then you cannot use this method.