# Why can base plots not be stored in a list?

Tags: r, list, plot

I run a loop and I need to store some plots in a list. Sometimes they are of different types, because I need to insert dummy plots when I cannot compute the actual plots.

Why is it that base plots cannot be stored in a list?

```
library(effects)
df=data.frame(response=sample(10,10),predictor=c(1:10))
model0=lm(response~predictor,df)
plot.list=list()
plot.list[[1]]=plot(Effect("predictor",model0))
plot.list[[2]]=plot(predictor~response,df)
plot.list
```

Comment: Because in base graphics (as opposed to ggplot2 or lattice) you draw directly on an active device. e.g. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29583849/324364).

Comment: alright, thank you. I could not find that in my searches, you could mark my question as a duplicate.

Comment: @kdarras check out `ggplot2` - the graph object is a list, works with grid arrange and can be stored in a list

Comment: I work a lot with ggplot, but some plots (qPlot, Cook's distance plots, standardized residual plots... are better handled by something else than ggplot)

Answer (score 0):

try storing functions

```
x <- list()
x[[1]] <- function(){plot(1)}
x[[2]] <- function(){plot(2)}
```

then

```
x[[1]]()
```

Comment: thanks, that works but effectively changes the structure of my list, making it less obvious to work with the different plot types inside my list. for example, grid.arrange does not work with those stored functions.