# saving a base r plot as an object that can be plotted in a multiplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, pryr

This question builds from a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583849/r-saving-a-plot-in-an-object) which shows how to easily store a plot as an `r` object with the `%<a-%` function from the `pryr` package.  Great! However, I now want to create a multiplot that combines a base r plot with 2 `ggplot` figures. I am using `grid.arrange` below.

Using the base r `cars` data I can make two `ggplot` figures.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(pryr)
library(gridExtra)

Fig1 <- qplot(speed, data=cars, geom="histogram")
Fig2 <- qplot(dist, speed, data=cars, geom="point")
```

I then make a figure with `plot`, and save the figure as an object using the `%<a-%` function from the `pryr` package. Slick.

```
Fig3 %<a-% plot(cars$speed, cars$dist)
Fig3
```

Lastly, I want to combine the 3 figures into a single plot as shown below.

```
Figs <- grid.arrange(Fig1, Fig2, Fig3,
                     layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,1,1,2,2), c(1,1,1,2,2), c(3,3,3,3,3)))
```

The code produces the following error:

```
Error in gList(list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

How can I save an base `r` plot to be combined with additional `ggplot` figures?

Comment: Seems like you should be using the accepted answer on that linked question, not the `%<a-%` since that doesn't return a grid object, that just re-runs the commands at a later time. If you want to use `grid.arrage`, you're going to want a grid object.

Comment: @MrFlick oh, I see now. I was not fully understanding the accepted answer to the linked post.  Indeed, using the `gridGraphics` approach works. Do you want to post an answer or should I remove the question as it is a bit superfluous...?

Comment: If you have code that makes your example work, I'd recommend answering your own question below because it could be useful to others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As correctly noted by @MrFlick, the [accepted answer linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583849/r-saving-a-plot-in-an-object) is a better approach than the `%<a-%` function which does not store a grid.

The code below produces the desired result.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(gridGraphics)
library(grid)

Fig1 <- qplot(speed, data=cars, geom="histogram")
Fig2 <- qplot(dist, speed, data=cars, geom="point")

plot(cars$speed, cars$dist)
grid.echo()
Fig3 <- grid.grab()

Figs <- grid.arrange(Fig1, Fig2, Fig3,
                     layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,1,1,2,2), c(1,1,1,2,2), c(3,3,3,3,3)))
```

Comment: I followed your answer to solve my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46261833/3766430) without success. Any suggestions?  I want to produce a multiplot using the graphs created from `plot`.