# Plotting quantile regression by variables in a single page

Tags: r, plot, gridextra, quantreg

I am running quantile regressions for several independent variables separately (same dependent). I want to plot only the slope estimates over several quantiles of each variable in a single plot.

Here's a toy data:

```
set.seed(1988)

y <- rnorm(50, 5, 3)
x1 <- rnorm(50, 3, 1)
x2 <- rnorm(50, 1, 0.5)

# Running Quantile Regression 
require(quantreg)
fit1 <- summary(rq(y~x1, tau=1:9/10), se="boot")
fit2 <- summary(rq(y~x2, tau=1:9/10), se="boot")
```

I want to plot only the slope estimates over quantiles. Hence, I am giving `parm=2` in `plot`.

```
 plot(fit1, parm=2)
 plot(fit2, parm=2)
```

Now, I want to combine both these plots in a single page.

What I have tried so far;

1. I tried setting `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` and plotting them. But it's producing a blank page.
2. I have tried using `gridExtra` and gridGraphics without success. Tried to convert base graphs into Grob objects as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33848995/3766430)
3. Tried using function `layout` function as in [this](http://seananderson.ca/courses/11-multipanel/multipanel.pdf) document
4. I am trying to look into the source code of `plot.rqs`. But I am unable to understand how it's plotting confidence bands (I'm able to plot only the coefficients over quantiles) or to change `mfrow` parameter there.

Can anybody point out where am I going wrong? Should I look into the source code of `plot.rqs` and change any parameters there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `quantreg::plot.summary.rqs` has an `mfrow` parameter, it uses it to override `par('mfrow')` so as to facet over `parm` values, which is not what you want to do.

One alternative is to parse the objects and plot manually. You can pull the tau values and coefficient matrix out of `fit1` and `fit2`, which are just lists of values for each tau, so in tidyverse grammar,

```r
library(tidyverse)

c(fit1, fit2) %>%    # concatenate lists, flattening to one level
    # iterate over list and rbind to data.frame
    map_dfr(~cbind(tau = .x[['tau']],    # from each list element, cbind the tau...
                   coef(.x) %>%    # ...and the coefficient matrix, 
                       data.frame(check.names = TRUE) %>%    # cleaned a little
                       rownames_to_column('term'))) %>% 
    filter(term != '(Intercept)') %>%    # drop intercept rows
    # initialize plot and map variables to aesthetics (positions)
    ggplot(aes(x = tau, y = Value, 
               ymin = Value - Std..Error, 
               ymax = Value + Std..Error)) + 
    geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.5) + 
    geom_line(color = 'blue') + 
    facet_wrap(~term, nrow = 2)    # make a plot for each value of `term`
```

[image: facetted plot]

Pull more out of the objects if you like, add the horizontal lines of the original, and otherwise go wild.

---

Another option is to use [`magick`](https://github.com/ropensci/magick#readme) to capture the original images (or save them with any device and reread them) and manually combine them:

```r
library(magick)

plots <- image_graph(height = 300)    # graphics device to capture plots in image stack
plot(fit1, parm = 2)
plot(fit2, parm = 2)
dev.off()

im1 <- image_append(plots, stack = TRUE)    # attach images in stack top to bottom

image_write(im1, 'rq.png')
```

[image: joined plots]

Comment: This works perfectly fine, though I can't decipher the code right now. Thanks for this way out.

Comment: I edited with some comments, plus a `magick` approach that's more direct.

Answer (score 0):

The function `plot` used by `quantreg` package has it's own mfrow parameter. If you do not specify it, it enforces some option which it chooses on it's own (and thus overrides your `par(mfrow = c(2,2))`.

Using the `mfrow` parameter within `plot.rqs`:

```
# make one plot, change the layout
plot(fit1, parm = 2, mfrow = c(2,1))
# add a new plot
par(new = TRUE)
# create a second plot
plot(fit2, parm = 2, mfrow = c(2,1))
```

Comment: I tried this. But when I increase the dimension of mfrow (because, I have more variables like the one I showed in OP), they don't get plotted in sequence. In `mfrow = c(2,2)`, first plot comes in top left (Grid - 1,1), the second one in bottom right (Grid - 2, 2) and the third gets overwritten on (2,2).