# How to return combined plot object in a function with single handler in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following code:

```
attach(mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
plot(wt,disp, main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
hist(wt, main="Histogram of wt")
boxplot(wt, main="Boxplot of wt")
```

Which create this:

[image]

What I want to do is to put those code inside a function so that 
it returns an object that holds these plots with a single handler.
How can I achieve that?

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
test_handle <- function() {

  attach(mtcars)
  par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
  plot(wt,disp, main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
  hist(wt, main="Histogram of wt")
  boxplot(wt, main="Boxplot of wt")

  # how can I put 4 objects into 1 handler and return it?

}
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Save a plot in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583849/save-a-plot-in-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

Write the function `return()` inside the function like this:

```
test_handle <- function() {
  attach(mtcars)
  return(par(mfrow=c(2,2)))
  plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
  plot(wt,disp, main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
  hist(wt, main="Histogram of wt")
  boxplot(wt, main="Boxplot of wt")
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried calling `test_handle()` it shows no plot.

Comment: Ohhh yes. I don't know what happened, but it worked on my computer. By the way, I copy/pasted and run your code and it worked for me