# Converting corrplot output to grob

Tags: r, r-corrplot, grob

I am trying to use grid.arrange to combine multiple types of graph/table, one of which is a correlation matrix using `corrplot`. Is there a way to convert a corrplot to a grob or export/import as an image compatible with `grid.arrange`? Since the other plots I'm combining are from ggplot and tableGrob, I can't seem to use `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))` or `layout(matrix(1:2))` as suggested in other posts.

```
P1 <- corrplot(PANAcor, order="hclust", addgrid.col = "gray",  
               type="full", col = col2(50), tl.cex=1.5, tl.col="black", 
               method="color", tl.pos="lt", tl.srt=45, hclust.method = "average",
               cl.ratio = 0.25, cl.align = "l", number.cex = 2)

summary <- grid.arrange(
    top=textGrob(sprintf("%s Summary",subject), gp=gpar(fontsize=16,font=8)),
    blank, P1, P2,
    blank, T1, T2,
    ncol=3, widths = c(0.1, 3, 3), 
    nrow=2, heights= c(1, 1),
    bottom = textGrob(sprintf("%s run %s",version,runtime), 
    gp=gpar(fontsize=6,font=8), hjust=-1)
  )
```

> Error in gList(list(1, 0.45, 0.62, 0.55, 0.68, 0.64, -0.13, -0.37,
>   -0.22,  :    only 'grobs' allowed in "gList" In addition: Warning message: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list

Data:

```
PANAcor <- structure(c(1, 0.56, 0.68, -0.49, -0.4, -0.39, 0.56, 1, 0.64, -0.55, 
                       -0.49, -0.54, 0.68, 0.64, 1, -0.69, -0.57, -0.65, -0.49,
                       -0.55, -0.69, 1, 0.82, 0.73, -0.4, -0.49, -0.57, 0.82, 1, 
                       0.71, -0.39, -0.54, -0.65, 0.73, 0.71, 1), 
                     .Dim = c(6L, 6L), 
                     .Dimnames = list(c("Anxious", "Irritable", "Upset", "Happy",
                                        "Enthusiastic", "Outgoing"), 
                                      c("Anxious", "Irritable", "Upset", "Happy", 
                                        "Enthusiastic", "Outgoing"))) 

col2 <- colorRampPalette(c("#7bffff","#7bbdff","#0000ff","black",
                           "#ff1a1a","#ff8000","#ffff4d"))
```

Comment: Have you seen the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583849/save-a-plot-in-an-object)? Sounds like `grid.echo` + `grid.grab` from the [gridGraphics package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridGraphics/index.html) can convert P1 to a grob for you.

Comment: I did try grid.echo + grid.grab, but it creates doubles/shifts everything (legend overlaps main plot, variable names overlap main plot and are no longer centered, columns overlap/are too narrow on the left half and have white space/are too wide on the right half) in a way I can't figure out how to undo.  I've tried different settings within grid.echo + grid.grab, but no luck.

Comment: Can you include the output of `dput(PANAcor)` (or some sample data that reproduces this problem) in your question? This would help others troubleshoot better.

Comment: An abbreviated version:

`structure(c(1, 0.56, 0.68, -0.49, -0.4, -0.39, 0.56, 1, 0.64, 
-0.55, -0.49, -0.54, 0.68, 0.64, 1, -0.69, -0.57, -0.65, -0.49, 
-0.55, -0.69, 1, 0.82, 0.73, -0.4, -0.49, -0.57, 0.82, 1, 0.71, 
-0.39, -0.54, -0.65, 0.73, 0.71, 1), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Anxious", "Irritable", "Upset", "Happy", "Enthusiastic", 
    "Outgoing"), c("Anxious", "Irritable", "Upset", "Happy", 
    "Enthusiastic", "Outgoing")))`

  `col2 <- colorRampPalette(c("#7bffff","#7bbdff","#0000ff","black","#ff1a1a","#ff8000","#ffff4d"))`

Answer (score 5):

`grid.echo` + `grid.grab` from the gridGraphics package will convert a graphic drawn by `corrplot` into an identical-looking grob. Trouble is, the grob only looks identical at the exact same graphics device size.

**Reproducing the problem**:

```
library(gridGraphics)
library(grid)

corrplot(PANAcor, order="hclust", addgrid.col = "gray",  
         type="full", col = col2(50), tl.cex=1.5, tl.col="black", 
         method="color", tl.pos="lt", tl.srt=45, hclust.method = "average",
         cl.ratio = 0.25, cl.align = "l", number.cex = 2)

## grab the scene as a grid object & save it to P1
grid.echo()
P1 <- grid.grab()

grid.draw(P1) # looks fine, until you resize the graphics device
```

Original size (looks identical to the graphic generated by `corrplot`:

[image: original size looks fine]

Larger size (coloured regions remain squares, even though the matrix has extended to rectangular cells, & don't extend to the edge of each cell):

[image: larger size with squares that don't cover the matrix]

Smaller size (coloured regions have a minimum height / width, which cause them to spill out beyond the confines of each cell):

[image: smaller size with squares that spill out]

And if we arrange multiple grobs together, it's almost certainly going to look weird:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(P1, P1, P1, layout_matrix = matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3), nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
```

[image: arranging 3 plots together]

In short, due to the way `corrplot` draws the graphic, all other children grobs in P1 adjust in sync when the graphics device is re-sized, except for the grob responsible for colour.

**Solution**:

```
# save correlation matrix colors to a vector, then make coloured matrix grob transparent
matrix.colors <- getGrob(P1, gPath("square"), grep = TRUE)[["gp"]][["fill"]]
P1 <- editGrob(P1,
               gPath("square"), grep = TRUE,
               gp = gpar(col = NA,
                         fill = NA))

# apply the saved colours to the underlying matrix grob
P1 <- editGrob(P1,
               gPath("symbols-rect-1"), grep = TRUE,
               gp = gpar(fill = matrix.colors))

# convert the background fill from white to transparent, while we are at it
P1 <- editGrob(P1,
               gPath("background"), grep = TRUE,
               gp = gpar(fill = NA))
```

Replace `gPath("square")` with `gPath("circle")` if you use `corrplot`'s default method. I haven't tested the other method options for the corresponding grob names, but the general principle should be similar.

**Check that everything's aligned now**:

```
grid.arrange(P1, P1, P1, layout_matrix = matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3), nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
```

[image: arranging 3 plots together after applying solution]

By the way, you may want to adjust the text size arguments in `corrplot`. Based on your current code, the labels appear rather large, and are liable to be cut off when you arrange multiple plots together.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I don't seem to have a few things defined. First it says:

**Error in numnotnull("fontsize") : object 'grid.matrix.colors' not found**

So I changed matrix.colors to grid.matrix.colors, and then got:

**Warning message:
In editGrob(P1, gPath("symbols-rect-1"), grep = TRUE, gp = gpar(fill = grid.matrix.colors)) :
  'gPath' (symbols-rect-1) not found**

Comment: Sorry, 1st one was a typo on my part. I changed the vector name half way through answering & didn't clean up the code consistently. For the 2nd one, what do you get if you enter `P1$childrenOrder`? That should give you the names of all children grobs to `P1`.

Comment: `P1$childrenOrder
 "graphics-background" "graphics-plot-1-symbols-square-1" "graphics-plot-1-symbols-square-2" "graphics-plot-1-symbols-square-3" "graphics-plot-1-rect-1" "graphics-plot-1-rect-2" "graphics-plot-1-segments-1" "graphics-plot-1-text-1"           "graphics-plot-1-text-2" "graphics-plot-1-text-3" "graphics-plot-1-main-1" "graphics-plot-1-rect-3"`

But then I either get "Subscript out of bounds" ([["x"]]) or "NA" (["x"]). 

Also, matrix.colors="white" (rather than multiple colors, not sure if it's supposed to say that). Thanks again, and sorry for all the difficulties!