# How to save a plot created by corrplot function in r

Tags: r, plot, correlation

I write a function that plots a correlation heatmap but I can not save the plot as an object.

```
library(corrplot)
library(psych)
myfun = function(ff){
   corrplot(ff$r, 
                p.mat = round(as.matrix(ff$p),3),
                method = 'circle',
                type = 'lower',
                sig.level = c(.001, .01, .05), 
                tl.pos="lt", 
                tl.col="black", tl.cex=1.3, 
                tl.offset=0.2,
                cl.pos="r",
                insig = "label_sig",
                pch.cex = 1.3,
                pch.col="red",
                cl.cex = 1.3)
  corrplot(ff$r,  type="upper", method="number",
                 col="coral4",  tl.pos="n", cl.pos="n", number.cex = 1.2, add=T,diag=F)
}
```

It indeed plots a correlation heatmap.

```
ff = corr.test(mtcars, method = 'spearman') 

myfun(ff)
```

The attributes of `myfun(ff)` is a `matrix` rather than a `plot`.

```
p = myfun(ff)
class(p)

> class(p)
[1] "matrix"
```

Also, I can not see the plot in the Plots window when I type `p` in the Console. It just gave me a correlation matrix.

```
> p
            mpg        cyl       disp         hp        drat         wt        qsec
mpg   1.0000000 -0.9108013 -0.9088824 -0.8946646  0.65145546 -0.8864220  0.46693575
cyl  -0.9108013  1.0000000  0.9276516  0.9017909 -0.67888119  0.8577282 -0.57235095
disp -0.9088824  0.9276516  1.0000000  0.8510426 -0.68359210  0.8977064 -0.45978176
hp   -0.8946646  0.9017909  0.8510426  1.0000000 -0.52012499  0.7746767 -0.66660602
drat  0.6514555 -0.6788812 -0.6835921 -0.5201250  1.00000000 -0.7503904  0.09186863
wt   -0.8864220  0.8577282  0.8977064  0.7746767 -0.75039041  1.0000000 -0.22540120
```

How can I save the plot created by `myfun()` as an object (such as `p`) so that I can use the object do some other things?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Read the documentation of `?corrplot`. Under value it says that `corrplot()` `(Invisibly) returns a reordered correlation matrix.` To get what you want, you need to grab the grob that it is producing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734543/converting-corrplot-output-to-grob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `corrplot()` says the following:

> ### Value
>
> (Invisibly) returns a reordered correlation matrix.

So what you want to get out of your function is the side effect of `corrplot()` (the plot) rather than the matrix.

One way to do that would be to use `recordPlot()` to "save" the latest plot:

```r
library(corrplot)
#> corrplot 0.84 loaded
library(psych)
myfun <- function(ff){
  corrplot(ff$r, 
           p.mat = round(as.matrix(ff$p),3),
           method = 'circle',
           type = 'lower',
           sig.level = c(.001, .01, .05), 
           tl.pos="lt", 
           tl.col="black", tl.cex=1.3, 
           tl.offset=0.2,
           cl.pos="r",
           insig = "label_sig",
           pch.cex = 1.3,
           pch.col="red",
           cl.cex = 1.3)
  corrplot(ff$r,  type="upper", method="number",
           col="coral4",  tl.pos="n", cl.pos="n", number.cex = 1.2, add=T,diag=F)
  recordPlot() # record the latest plot
}
ff <- corr.test(mtcars, method = 'spearman')

myfun(ff) # shows the plot
p <- myfun(ff) # still shows the plot but also saves it
```

[image]

```r
p # show the recorded plot
class(p)
#> [1] "recordedplot"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>