# How to assign the (image) output of a basic plot() in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to assign `plot()` output in the same way as ggplot2 output?

e.g.

```
my_plot <- plot(c(1,2,3))

my_plot
# [1] NULL
```

The above doesn't work, but the following (for ggplot) does:

```
library(ggplot2)
my_ggplot <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = 1:3, y = c(1,2,3))) + geom_point()

# Running this will show the plot
my_ggplot
```

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent you are correct it's the same question. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `recordPlot()` method

Check This Answer
[Save a plot in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583849/save-a-plot-in-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful, here's an extremely simple example that works

```
plot(1:15) # make plot
p <- recordPlot() # assign plot
p # view plot
```