# Cannot store a radar plot into a R object

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

I was trying to store a radar plot into an object `p1` but every time I got a result of `null`. I tried other ggplot2 plots and they all worked fine of being put into objects. My ultimate intention is to use the `patchwork` to put one radar plot and one line plot side by side. Any suggestion?

```
library(fmsb)
set.seed(99)
data <-as.data.frame(matrix( sample( 2:20 , 10 , replace=T) , ncol=10))
colnames(data) <- c("math" , "english" , "biology" , "music" , "R-coding", "data-viz" , "french" , "physic", "statistic", "sport" )

# To use the fmsb package, I have to add 2 lines to the dataframe: the max and min of each topic to show on the plot!
data <-rbind(rep(20,10) , rep(0,10) , data)


# Custom the radarChart !
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
p1 <- radarchart( data, axistype=1, 
                  
                  #custom polygon
                  pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5) , plwd=4 , 
                  
                  #custom the grid
                  cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,20,5), cglwd=0.8,
                  
                  #custom labels
                  vlcex=0.6 
)

> p1
NULL
```

Comment: If you read the help file for `?radarchart`, you can see under Value, `No value is returned.` Under the hood, `radarchart` is using `plot`, which also returns no value. This question is about saving a base plot as an object. Do any of the answers work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583849/save-a-plot-in-an-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Save a plot in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583849/save-a-plot-in-an-object)

radarchart is not a ggplot2 function, so uses base plot. You can't write base plot to an object but can

If you want ggplot

```
# Run Once Only
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar")
```

```
# Run rest as usual
library(ggplot2)
library(ggradar)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
set.seed(99)
mydata <-as.data.frame(matrix( sample( 2:20 , 10 , replace=T) , ncol=10))
colnames(mydata) <- c("math" , "english" , "biology" , "music" , "R-coding", "data-viz" , "french" , "physic", "statistic", "sport" )

# To use the fmsb package, I have to add 2 lines to the dataframe: the max and min of each topic to show on the plot!
mydata <-rbind(rep(20,10) , rep(0,10) , mydata)


p1 <- ggradar(
  mydata[3, ], 
  values.radar = c("0", "10", "20"),
  grid.min = 0, grid.mid = 10, grid.max = 20
)

p1
```

You would obviously need to play with the formatting

OR if you want to use base R:

par(mfrow=c(3,1)) will output each new figure into a 3 x 1 grid... but far less controllable than ggplot

Comment: Thanks and this makes sense (base plot vs ggplot object).

Answer (score 0):

## Put 2 plots side by side

This is an answer to your 'ultimate goal', and not to your question.

Why don't you use [par(mfrow)](https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/arranging-plots-with-parmfrow-and-layout.html)?

```
library(fmsb)
set.seed(99)
data <-as.data.frame(matrix( sample( 2:20 , 10 , replace=T) , ncol=10))
colnames(data) <- c("math" , "english" , "biology" , "music" , "R-coding", "data-viz" , "french" , "physic", "statistic", "sport" )

data <-rbind(rep(20,10) , rep(0,10) , data)

par(mfrow = c(2, 1)) # TWO IMAGES SIDE BY SIZE

# YOUR FIRST PLOT
radarchart( data, axistype=1, 
                  pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5), plwd=4, 
                  cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey",
                  caxislabels=seq(0,20,5), cglwd=0.8,
                  vlcex=0.6)

# YOUR SECOND PLOT
...... # no need to do anything if it uses base plot (like radarchart)
# if the 2nd plot does not use base plot (i.e., it's from ggplot), then do a
plot(yourSecondPlot)
```