# Show(plot(hc)) returns NULL when using hclust in R

Tags: r, null, cluster-computing, hclust

I am using VSCode and I am trying to visualize a dendrogram produced by hclust(). My data set (baseMini) is made of 2d vectors and so far this is what I have done:

```
dd <- dist(x = baseMini, method = "euclidean")
hc <- hclust(d = dd, method = "complete")
plot_hc <- plot(x = hc)
```

I confirmed that dd is a distance matrix, it looks something like this:

```
              1          2          3       3000       3001       3002
2     1.6710624
3     0.9892719  2.0635176                                            
3000  6.4243003  7.9459624  5.9004292
3001  6.3986419  7.9904130  5.9925833  0.8342891
3002  7.6690587  8.9921632  6.9431019  2.1140049  2.8991615
6001  7.5003784  5.9874636  7.3277637 12.6488917 12.9759681 12.8943846
```

Then, trying to check hc I get something like this (I really don't know what to expect as an hclust() output):

```
> hc

Call:
hclust(d = dd, method = "complete")

Cluster method   : complete
Distance         : euclidean
Number of objects: 7
```

However, when I want to show the plot with show(plot_hc) or even just ask for plot_hc I get a NULL output. Everywhere I looked for they always use these same steps and never mention any particular library or anything else. What am I missing and why can't VSCode/R recognize the plot?

Additional info:
I tried asking with plot.hclust(hc) but I get that there is no function "plot.hclust".
Another thing that could be is that at the beginning of the file I used the library(ggplot) and I don't know if it interferes somehow with plot(). Also, maybe the error is in how I prepared my data set, but it looks pretty standard:

```
> baseMini
             X1        X2
1     2.1135390 0.3644160
2     0.4427359 0.3938498
3     2.2764659 1.3401791
3000  7.8718230 3.2128892
3001  8.1685351 2.4331455
3002  7.9622546 5.3249591
6001 -4.7765455 3.3279293
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stumped me also. It's not an issue with it being an `hclust` object but rather how the `plot()` function works. `ggplot()` outputs save nicely to your environment but it doesn't work the same for `plot()`. I saw a few approaches that recommend using `recordPlot()`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29583945/4650934) can provide more detail and another approach. Good luck.

```r
# these steps don't work
doesnt_work <- plot(1:3, 1:3)
doesnt_work
#> NULL

# but these steps do
plot(1:3, 1:3)    # make plot
p <- recordPlot() # assign existing plot outputoutput
plot.new()        # clean up device
p                 # redraw
```

Comment: Yes! It worked like a charm. Thank you so much!