# Identifying uniroot for multiple independent variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, threshold, uniroot

I am trying to calculate the value of x where y = 0. I could able to do it for single x using the following code

```
lm.model <- lm(y ~ x)
cc <- coef(lm.model)

f <- function(x) cc[2]*x + cc[1] 
plot(x, y)
abline(coef(lm.model))
abline(h=0, col="blue")

(threshold <- uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 100))$root)
abline(v=threshold, col="blue")
```

[image]

```
x = c(33.05, 14.22, 15.35, 13.52, 8.7, 13.73, 8.28, 21.02, 9.97, 
11.98, 12.87, 5.05, 11.23, 11.65, 10.05, 12.58, 13.88, 9.66, 
4.62, 4.56, 5.35, 3.7, 3.29, 4.87, 3.75, 6.55, 4.51, 7.77, 4.7, 
4.18, 25.14, 18.08, 10.41)
y = c(16.22699279, 15.78620732, 9.656361014, -17.32805679, -20.85685895, 
7.601993251, -4.776053714, 10.50972236, 3.853479771, 7.713563136, 
8.579366561, 14.16989395, 7.484692081, -1.2807472, -12.13759458, 
-0.29138513, -5.238157067, -2.033194068, -38.12157566, -33.61912493, 
-9.763657548, -0.240863712, 9.090638907, 7.345492608, 6.949676888, 
-19.94866471, 0.995659732, -1.162616185, 5.497998429, 1.656653092, 
2.116687436, 22.23175649, 10.33039543)
```

But I have multiple x variables. Now how can I apply it for multiple x variables at a time?
Here is an example data

```
df = structure(list(y = c(16.2269927925813, 15.7862073196372, 9.65636101412767, 
-17.3280567922775, -20.8568589521297, 7.6019932507973, -4.77605371404423, 
10.5097223644541, 3.85347977129367, 7.71356313645697, 8.57936656085966, 
14.1698939499927, 7.4846920807874, -1.28074719969249, -12.1375945758837, 
-0.291385130176774, -5.23815706681139, -2.03319406769161, -38.1215756639013, 
-33.6191249261727, -9.76365754821171, -0.240863712421707, 9.09063890677045, 
7.34549260800693, 6.94967688778232, -19.9486647079697, 0.995659731521127, 
-1.16261618452931, 5.49799842947493, 1.65665309209479, 2.11668743610013, 
22.2317564898722, 10.3303954315884), x1 = c(8.56, 8.66, 9.09, 
8.36, 8.3, 8.63, 8.78, 8.44, 8.34, 8.46, 8.33, 8.19, 8.58, 8.65, 
8.75, 8.34, 8.77, 9.06, 9.31, 9.11, 9.26, 9.81, 9.68, 9.79, 9.26, 
9.53, 8.89, 8.89, 10.37, 9.58, 10.27, 10.16, 10.27), x2 = c(164, 
328.3, 0, 590.2, 406.6, 188.4, 423.8, 355.3, 337.6, 0, 0, 200.1, 
0, 315.8, 547.5, 225.6, 655.7, 387.2, 0, 487.4, 400.4, 0, 234.9, 
275.5, 0, 0, 613.2, 207.4, 184.4, 162.8, 220, 174.8, 0), x3 = c(4517.7, 
2953.4, 2899.3, 2573.8, 3310.7, 3880.3, 3016.8, 3552.3, 2960.1, 
323, 2638.5, 3343.1, 3274.7, 3218, 3268.3, 3507.9, 3709.2, 3537.5, 
2634.4, 1964.6, 3333.7, 2809.7, 3326.8, 3524.5, 3893.9, 3166.7, 
3992.1, 4324.7, 3077.9, 3069.9, 4218.9, 3897.4, 2693.9), x4 = c(14.7, 
14.5, 15.5, 17, 16.2, 15.9, 15.7, 15.3, 13.5, 14, 15.4, 16.2, 
15.6, 15.7, 15.1, 15.8, 15.3, 14.9, 15.7, 16.3, 15.21000004, 
16.7, 15.6, 16.2, 15.7, 16.3, 17.3, 16.9, 15.7, 14.9, 13.81999969, 
14.90754509, 12.42847157), x5 = c(28.3, 29.1, 28.3, 29.1, 28.7, 
29.3, 28.9, 28.4, 29.3, 29.3, 29.1, 29, 29.9, 29.5, 28.4, 30.3, 
29.1, 29.1, 29, 29.5, 29.3, 28.5, 29, 28.7, 29.4, 28.8, 29.2, 
30.1, 28.3, 28.7, 24.96999931, 25.79496384, 25.3072052), x6 = c(33.05, 
14.22, 15.35, 13.52, 8.7, 13.73, 8.28, 21.02, 9.97, 11.98, 12.87, 
5.05, 11.23, 11.65, 10.05, 12.58, 13.88, 9.66, 4.62, 4.56, 5.35, 
3.7, 3.29, 4.87, 3.75, 6.55, 4.51, 7.77, 4.7, 4.18, 25.14, 18.08, 
10.41), x7 = c(13.8425, 11.1175, 8.95, 13.5375, 5.4025, 13.5625, 
13.735, 14.14, 8.0875, 5.565, 12.255, 3.3075, 6.345, 4.8125, 
4.0325, 11.475, 10.32, 17.71, 2.3375, 3.92, 5.7, 2.42, 8.3075, 
7.4725, 7.7925, 10.8725, 8.005, 11.7475, 13.405, 8.425, 47.155, 
26.1, 6.6675), x8 = c(0.95, 3.01, 1.92, 1.51, 2.61, 1.32, 3.55, 
1.21, 2.14, 1.1, 1.32, 0.76, 1.34, 5.41, 9.38, 6.55, 4.44, 7.37, 
9.84, 12.68, 15.52, 23.01, 18.59, 21.64, 19.69, 25.22, 22.38, 
25.03, 37.42, 22.26, 2.1, 3.01, 0.82), x9 = c(26.2, 25.8, 25.8, 
25.5, 26, 24.7, 22.9, 25.3, 26.3, 26.1, 22.5, 25.9, 26.4, 25.2, 
25.8, 25.4, 25, 23.2, 26.4, 25.8, 26.6, 26.2, 25.8, 26.8, 25, 
25.4, 25.6, 26.1, 25.7, 25.8, 24.78000069, 24.98148918, 26.39899826
), x10 = c(35.4, 39, 37.5, 36.4, 37.1, 36.2, 37.3, 36.4, 37.5, 
36, 36.6, 35.6, 37.3, 38.3, 37, 37.5, 37.5, 39.6, 37.8, 36.8, 
36.6, 38.4, 38.9, 38.4, 38.4, 37.7, 39.1, 37.7, 37.8, 39.4, 36.25, 
35.57029343, 35.57416534), x11 = c(653.86191565, 383.1, 457.1, 
591.4, 549.2, 475.2, 626.4, 308.8, 652.4, 77, 380.9, 530.5, 393, 
712.1, 623.4, 515.7, 706.4, 713.4, 343.7, 559.5, 630.1, 292.3, 
578.6, 628.88904574, 480.96959685, 591.35600287, 804.8, 419.6, 
403.7, 361.2, 515.07101438, 434.66682808, 299.9531298), x12 = c(163.9793854, 
167.9, 135, 215.8, 213, 188.4, 260.6, 191.8, 337.6, 55, 147.6, 
200.1, 140.7, 315.8, 189.6, 225.6, 469.3, 201.8, 140, 297.2, 
204.6, 142.5, 234.9, 275.494751, 153.7796173, 147.6174622, 433.6, 
207.4, 184.4, 162.8, 219.9721832, 174.8355713, 106.8163605), 
    x13 = c(92, 67, 67, 50, 70, 87, 68, 86, 70, 11, 66, 79, 70, 
    61, 75, 78, 78, 77, 69, 35, 72, 76, 69, 84, 93, 73, 81, 99, 
    80, 76, 101, 86, 80), x14 = c(70, 42, 46, 34, 55, 60, 51, 
    65, 49, 1, 40, 56, 54, 41, 48, 57, 46, 50, 41, 22, 47, 47, 
    49, 57, 70, 52, 56, 70, 48, 50, 74, 66, 47), x15 = c(21, 
    12, 13, 10, 14, 16, 10, 13, 10, 0, 9, 14, 16, 20, 14, 14, 
    13, 15, 10, 7, 17, 8, 14, 14, 14, 11, 17, 19, 12, 11, 17, 
    17, 9), x16 = c(1076.8, 783.7, 711.8, 1041.9, 957.4, 939.3, 
    662.9, 768.1, 770.3, 0, 399.2, 606.2, 724.1, 960.8, 943.8, 
    737.8, 1477.4, 1191.7, 371.3, 956.4, 1251.7, 345.7, 1210.7, 
    845, 598.1, 821.7, 1310.6, 940.1, 581, 520, 313.5, 606.8, 
    201.2), x17 = c(163.9793854, 167.9, 128.4, 215.8, 213, 188.4, 
    260.6, 191.8, 337.6, 55, 147.6, 200.1, 140.7, 315.8, 189.6, 
    225.6, 469.3, 201.8, 140, 297.2, 204.6, 142.5, 234.9, 157.7472534, 
    153.7796173, 147.6174622, 133.1873627, 150.2, 184.4, 162.8, 
    219.9721832, 174.8355713, 106.8163605)), row.names = c(NA, 
33L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `purrr::map` to loop through every x.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

thresholds <- df %>%
  select(-y) %>%
  map_dbl(function(x){
    lm.model <- lm(df$y ~ x)
    cc <- coef(lm.model)
    
    f <- function(x) cc[2]*x + cc[1] 
    plot(x, df$y)
    abline(coef(lm.model))
    abline(h=0, col="blue")
    
    threshold <- tryCatch(uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 100))$root, error = function(cond){NA})
    abline(v=threshold, col="blue")
    
    return(threshold)})
```

For some x's, `uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 100))$root` yields an error: Error

> in uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 100)) :    f() values at end points not of opposite sign

So the `tryCatch` is used to return `NA` for the threshold associated with that x, instead of breaking the code.

Result:

```
> thresholds
       x1        x2        x3        x4        x5        x6        x7        x8        x9 
 9.023314        NA        NA 15.459841 28.727293 10.514728 10.493577  9.669244 25.522480 
      x10       x11       x12       x13       x14       x15       x16       x17 
37.370852        NA        NA 73.398380 50.239522 13.022176        NA        NA
```

### Edit: binding the graphs together

```
graphs <- df %>%
  select(-y) %>%
  imap(function(x, name){
    lm.model <- lm(df$y ~ x)
    cc <- coef(lm.model)
    
    f <- function(x) cc[2]*x + cc[1] 
    threshold <- tryCatch(uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 100))$root, error = function(cond){NA})
    
    g = ggplot(mapping = aes(x)) +
      geom_point(aes(y = df$y)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = cc[2]*x + cc[1])) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "blue") +
      labs(title = name, y = "y", x = "x")
    
    if(!is.na(threshold)) {g = g + geom_vline(xintercept = threshold, color = "blue")}
    
    return(g)})

ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = graphs)
```

Result:

[image]

Obs2: i assumed that you don't need the `thresholds` vector defined in the first attempt, if you still need it, it's easy to add it back to the answer
Obs1: let me know if you want any aesthetic change on the graphs

### Edit 2: graph with common axis

To use a common axis is better to use facets instead of `ggarrange`. In order to do that, we need to first save the fitted data for all variables, then plot, so the `ggplot` expression goes out of the `map`. Also, we now save the `treshold` info.

```
graphs <- df %>%
  select(-y) %>%
  imap(function(x, name){
    lm.model <- lm(df$y ~ x)
    cc <- coef(lm.model)
  
    f <- function(x) cc[2]*x + cc[1] 
    threshold <- tryCatch(uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 100))$root, error = function(cond){NA})
    
    list(threshold = threshold,
         data = tibble(y = df$y, "name" = name, "x" = x, "fitted" = cc[2]*x + cc[1]))})
```

Now we use the `purrr::transpose()` function to build a dataset for the `data` and other for the `treshold`. This functions does something like:

> list(x1 = list(treshold, data), x2 = ...) >>> list(treshold = list(x1, x2, ...), data = list(x1, x2, ...))

```
df2 = graphs %>%
  transpose() %>%
  `$`(data) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, paste0("x", 1:17)))

thresholds = graphs %>%
  transpose() %>%
  `$`(threshold) %>%
  {tibble(int = as.numeric(.), name = names(.))} #both datasets have the name column, to be used inside `facet_wrap()`
  
ggplot(df2, aes(x)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = fitted)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(name), scales = "free_x") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "blue") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = int), thresholds, color = "blue", linetype = 2) +
  geom_label(aes(label = round(int, 2), x = int*1, y = min(df$y)), thresholds, size = 4)
```

Result:

[image]

Obs1: the labels position and size can be easily altered. Another option is using the thresholds as a axis break
Obs2: this method can be slow for large datasets. A more efficient option is to save only `threshold` and `cc` inside `map`, and then building the dataset after it.

Comment: How to get the plots also?

Comment: I kept the `plot` and `abline` functions, so they should be being plotted in the graphics window. In my machine they are, at least. If you want, you can modify the code and save the plots in a list (read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583849/save-a-plot-in-an-object)