# How to include a plot as a possible output to call in an R function?

Tags: r, function

Code:

```
example <- function(x, y){
  Plot <- plot(x, y)
  return(list(Plot = Plot, Mean = c(mean(x), mean(y))))
}

set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(10)
set.seed(2)
y <- rnorm(10)
example(x, y)
```

The plot will come out every time we call the function `example(x, y)`. How can I not print the plot when I call the function `example(x, y)`, but could obtain the plot thru `example(x, y)$Plot` when needed?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583849/save-a-plot-in-an-object

Comment: @user20650 from what I have tried, ```recordPlot()``` does not work in my R 4.3.0. The ```example(x,y)``` still prints the plot immediately.

Comment: Why not use `example(x,y)$Mean` to get the mean and then `example(x,y)$Plot` for the plot?

Comment: @Jamie because that is not the most intuitive way how most people use R, and I am writing an R function for others to use.

Comment: I didnt try recordPlot, but you could use the other answer by chaging the relevant line of your code to `Plot <- function() plot(x, y)` , then call with `ex = example(1:3, 1:3); ex$Plot()`

Comment: @user20650 Your code works but I would rather find an option with ```ex$Plot```, without the ```()```, because most users won't call an object in that way. As mentioned, I am writing a function for others to use and I wish to make it as usual as it can be.

Comment: I suppose the easiest option is to use grid graphics then ... id suggest the `lattice` package as it ships with R

Comment: @user20650 I am not familiar with that option. Could you elaborate it more with the ```example()```? Thanks!

Comment: One option would be to include a new param such as `incl_plot = T`. Then use a conditional to either include or exclude the plot in the output.

Comment: @Jamie If the plot is excluded in the output, how can one call it? My point was to include the option to call the plot if someone wants to grab it. But in general, it won't print when people call the function.

Comment: `Plot <- lattice::xyplot(y ~ x)`

Comment: @user20650 The plot still prints when I call ```example(x, y)```.

Comment: not if you assign it to an object. if you then want the plot call `ex$Plot`

Comment: @user20650 ```example <- function(x, y){
  Plot <- lattice::xyplot(y ~ x)
  return(list(Plot = Plot, Mean = c(mean(x), mean(y))))
}

set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(10)
set.seed(2)
y <- rnorm(10)
example(x, y)
``` It still prints.

Comment: `ex = example(x, y)` .

Comment: @user20650 sorry that is not what I want because most R users won't use a function that way. Also, ```ex <- example(x,y)``` does not print the plot without using ```lattice``` either.

Comment: "*most R users won't use a function that way.*" ... disagree. But it is not what you want. Sorry I dont understand your second sentence .. to plot use `ex$Plot`

Comment: @user20650 I could be wrong in understanding how people without much programming background use R. My second sentence wanted to say that , if we use the original ```example()``` in my question, and call it in the way of ```ex <- example(x,y)```, the plot will not print. So we don't need ```lattice``` if we are to do ```ex <- example (x,y)```. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253572/discussion-between-j-z-and-user20650).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more sophisticated solution would be to use S3 dispatch, so that when you look at the whole output you only see the plot call, but when you look at the plot object, you get the actual plot drawn. This requires your main function and two print methods:

```r
example <- function(x, y, ...) {
  
  plot_call <- substitute(
    plot(x = x, y = y, ...)
    )
  
  args <- as.list(plot_call)[-1]
  args$x <- x
  args$y <- y
  if(! "xlab" %in% names(args)) args$xlab <- deparse(substitute(x))
  if(! "ylab" %in% names(args)) args$ylab <- deparse(substitute(y))
  recording <- as.call(c(quote(plot), args))

  Plot <- structure(list(plot_call = plot_call, 
                         recording = recording),
                    class = "Plot")
  
  structure(list(Plot = Plot, 
                 Mean = c(mean(x), mean(y))),
            class = "myclass")
}

print.Plot <- function(obj, ...) {
  eval(obj$recording)
  invisible(obj)
}

print.myclass <- function(obj, ...) {
  print(list(Plot = obj$Plot$plot_call,
             Mean = obj$Mean))
  invisible(obj)
}
```

This gives the following behaviour:

```r
example(x, y)
#> $Plot
#> plot(x = x, y = y)
#> 
#> $Mean
#> [1] 0.1322028 0.2111516
```

But

```r
example(x, y)$Plot
```

[image]

and

```r
my_obj <- example(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, col = "red")

my_obj
#> $Plot
#> plot(x = mtcars$wt, y = mtcars$mpg, col = "red")
#> 
#> $Mean
#> [1]  3.21725 20.09062
```

but

```r
my_obj$Plot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Edit**

It seems the OP is looking for a function that outputs a multiple plot page using `cowplot` but with the option of the user accessing individual plots. This could be done more easily, this time using a single `print` method:

```r
library(ggplot2)

example <- function(x, y) {

  df <- data.frame(x, y)

  plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
  plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_density()
  plot3 <- ggplot(df, aes(y)) + geom_density()
  plot4 <- ggplot(df, aes(sort(x), sort(y))) + geom_point() + geom_abline()

  structure(list(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4), class = "multiplot")
}

print.multiplot <- function(x, ...) {
  print(cowplot::plot_grid(x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]], x[[4]]))
}
```

This allows:

```
example(x, y)
```

[image]

but allows individual plots to be accessed too:

```r
example(x, y)[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to modify this to accommodate ```ggplot```? For example,  suppose I have a ```ggplot``` named ```Plot```, could you please help on how can I use your method to achieve our goal?

Comment: @J.Z. It's much easier with ggplot because it is already an object. Are you planning to use ggplot in your actual application? What exactly would you want the output of `example(x, y)` to display?

Comment: I actually was using the ggplot in my function but thought it would be easier to demonstrate the question here with ```plot```, because I thought my ggplots are quite complicated to be included here. To try to describe it, my function constructs four ggplots, and they are combined together with ```cowplot::plot_grid(plot0, plot1, plot2, plot3)```. While my function is to print the ```cowplot``` and some other output, I wish to add an option so that users can call individual plot when needed.

Comment: @J.Z. see my edit - is that what you mean?

Comment: It can't be better! Exactly what I wish to have! Neat and nice! Thank you!

Comment: I notice that you put ```print.multiplot``` outside the function ```example```. I tried to move it into the function ```example```, and it does not work. Is there a way to pack the ```print.multiplot``` into the function ```example```? Thank you!

Comment: @J.Z. no, the whole point is that the function produces a special type of object, but outside of the function R needs to know how to deal with these objects. If you are writing a package, you can have it so that `print.multiplot` is not exported. This means it isn't visible to end users. This is true of most R objects, including ggplot.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask for a resource that can help me to include it in a package but is not visible to end users?

Comment: @J.Z. Sure, you just need to ensure it is not exported. If you are using roxygen, just leave out the `@export` from the roxygen header. Otherwise, just leave it out from your NAMESPACE exports

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to add a parameter to let the user decide whether they want to include the plot in the output.

```
example <- function(x, y, incl_plot = T) {
  
  Mean = c(mean(x), mean(y))

  if(incl_plot) {
    Plot = plot(x,y)
    list(Plot = Plot, Mean = Mean)
  } else {
    Mean
  }
}

example(x,y, incl_plot = F) # only the Mean is returned
example(x,y) # both objects are returned
```

Comment: Thanks! This would work. I look forward to seeing if others have other options that may be neater.