# Saving a PNG file from a gtable of ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

I have created a facet_grid, and as some of the panels had no data, I created a gtable and specified which ones I wanted to be blank (otherwise the panels could be showing very low values).

This is the code I have used to create a gtable (found on stack overflow) :)

```
myplot2 <-
myplot %>%
  # Generate gtable of ggplot object
  ggplot2::ggplot_build() %>% ggplot2::ggplot_gtable() %>%
  # Modify gtable by filtering out grobs based on name using a regex pattern
  # $ represents end of string. Otherwise 'panel-1-1' removes 'panel-1-10', too.
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-1$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-5$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-6$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-2-1$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-2-5$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-2-6$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-3-1$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-3-3$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-5-5$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-5-5$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-6$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-1$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-2$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-5$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-6$", invert = TRUE) %>%
    # Plot the modified gtable
  {grid::grid.newpage(); grid::grid.draw(.)}
```

However I am now unable to save the resulting image. I am using rmarkdown, so it doesn't appear in my 'plot' tab. I have tried the following (again from stack overflow), as well as other combinations of the 'save' function, but its not working.

```
png("myfile.png"); plot(myplot2); dev.off()
```

Grateful if someone could help me save a png file. Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error message? Have you specified a correct pathway with `setwd()`?

Comment: Hi thanks for your swift response. Yes the working directory is set. I got the following error message.                        
                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                  
 Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

Comment: Does `plot(myplot2)` alone works when you chunk?

Comment: No, when I run ```plot(myplot2)``` I get the same error messge ```Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values```

Comment: Just ran the code without attributing it to an object (ie began with ```myplot %>%```) and that still works fine, and draws the plot. However when I add the ```myplot %>%``` again (as in the code in my original question), I've noticed that in my list of values in the Environment window, it says myplot2 NULL. Not sure if that's relevant or not.

Comment: I don't think you need `plot(myplot2)` but `grid::grid.newpage(); grid::grid.draw(myplot2)`.

Comment: This may help you  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349368/error-in-plot-window-need-finite-xlim-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. @teunbrand your suggestion worked. I've added 'myplot' into the code as you suggested, and the png is saved.

```
myplot2 <-
myplot %>%
  # Generate gtable of ggplot object
  ggplot2::ggplot_build() %>% ggplot2::ggplot_gtable() %>%
  # Modify gtable by filtering out grobs based on name using a regex pattern
  # $ represents end of string. Otherwise 'panel-1-1' removes 'panel-1-10', too.
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-1$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-5$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-6$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-2-1$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-2-5$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-2-6$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-3-1$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-3-3$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-5-5$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-5-5$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-6$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-1$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-2$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-5$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-6$", invert = TRUE) %>%
    # Plot the modified gtable
  {grid::grid.newpage(); grid::grid.draw(myplot)} 


png("../images/all sites by year.png", width = 10, height = 7, units = 'in', res = 300); plot(myplot2); dev.off()
```