# R plot - need finite xlim values but all x are finite with no NA's

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot the following variables:

```
> df1$var1
 [1] "2012Q1" "2012Q2" "2012Q3" "2012Q4" "2013Q1" "2013Q2" "2013Q3" "2013Q4" "2014Q1" "2014Q2"
[11] "2014Q3" "2014Q4" "2015Q1" "2015Q2" "2015Q3" "2015Q4" "2016Q1" "2016Q2" "2016Q3" "2016Q4"
[21] "2017Q1" "2017Q2" "2017Q3" "2017Q4" "2018Q1" "2018Q2" "2018Q3" "2018Q4" "2019Q1" "2019Q2"

> df1$var2
 [1]        NA        NA        NA        NA  444618.3 1556125.2  744145.1  844862.2  773188.2
[10] 1204732.2 1832308.2 1732186.6 1475089.7 1238791.2  772359.0  927111.5  982978.9  581415.1
[19]  489457.8  446419.0  403841.0  654630.9  753729.4  513755.0  587031.5  465808.7  462710.4
[28]  537923.9  409037.8  785118.7
```

using the following code:

```
plot(df1$var1,df1$var2,type="l",col="red")
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

how can I make it work?

Comment: Please add a reproducible minimal example. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how to make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: x and y must be numeric, it is trying to convert and all turns into NA, then we are getting NAs. Try: `plot(as.factor(df1$var1), df1$var2,type="l",col="red")`. See linked posts.

Comment: @zx8754 thanks. how can I get a line in my plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User [@zx8754](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680068/zx8754) marked this question as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349368/error-in-plot-window-need-finite-xlim-values) and of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009203/plot-a-character-vector-against-a-numeric-vector-in-r).

The problem here is that `var1` is of class `"character"`, like in the questions believed to be duplicates, but it is obvious from its contents that what is needed is a `year/quarter` object.
Package `zoo` has a function ideal for this, `as.yearqtr`.

```
yq <- zoo::as.yearqtr(df1$var1)
plot(yq, df1$var2, type = "l", col = "red")
```

[image]

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(var1 = c("2012Q1", "2012Q2", "2012Q3", "2012Q4", 
"2013Q1", "2013Q2", "2013Q3", "2013Q4", "2014Q1", "2014Q2", "2014Q3", 
"2014Q4", "2015Q1", "2015Q2", "2015Q3", "2015Q4", "2016Q1", "2016Q2", 
"2016Q3", "2016Q4", "2017Q1", "2017Q2", "2017Q3", "2017Q4", "2018Q1", 
"2018Q2", "2018Q3", "2018Q4", "2019Q1", "2019Q2"), var2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 444618.3, 1556125.2, 744145.1, 844862.2, 773188.2, 
1204732.2, 1832308.2, 1732186.6, 1475089.7, 1238791.2, 772359, 
927111.5, 982978.9, 581415.1, 489457.8, 446419, 403841, 654630.9, 
753729.4, 513755, 587031.5, 465808.7, 462710.4, 537923.9, 409037.8, 
785118.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: Nice, you made one extra step towards their goal. But the Q as it stands "why this error" is a duplicate of linked posts "because you can't have NAs for x". I'd keep it closed.

Comment: @zx8754 It's true that the question title was not clear. I have edited the question title adding that all x are finite with no `NA`'s.